# Not null lexical environment for eval

Tags: common-lisp

How to evaluate some lisp code using eval in not null lexical environment ? I need this feature for proper interpolation functionality.

Comment: It's not possible, however you should perhaps change your question to the actual problem rather than your problems regarding your chosen solution since this smells like a XY problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, actually, I just needed to be sure there's no way how to do it. Actually, I decided to send hash table with values instead of accessing environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you model your environment as bindings like those found in `let`:

```
((x 3) (y 2))
```

... then you can evaluate any form `f` with those bindings in place, like so:

```
(eval `(let ,e ,f))
```

This is the simplest case, but you can easily convert your data to fit this syntax. You can also bind functions, macros, etc. if needed.

Note that if you need values at runtime, then maybe dynamic bindings are better. You can use hash-tables, etc. but note that there is also the lesser-known [`PROGV`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm) special operator:

> Among other things, progv is useful when writing interpreters for languages embedded in Lisp; it provides a handle on the mechanism for binding dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think the OP knows the answer already, let me try to give a somewhat more descriptive solution, hoping more experienced lispers can point to mistakes I may make below:

As @coredump mentions, progv is an option as well as a let form in eval. Here is an example:

Let's create a list with some numbers and a cons that has a lambda form, bypassing the reader lambda conversion:

```
(setf list1 '(1 
              1 
              (lambda () 
                (print a))))
```

we can eval:

```
(eval
  `(let ((a 3))  
     ;; statement after comma is turned to a function by the reader. 
     ;; same effect with explicit (funcall (function ,(third list1)))
     ;;   because of the (lambda ..) macro form
     (funcall ,(third list1))))
3
3
```

Note that variable a above is lexical, not special.

now, with progv we can create special variables and eval will use them.
Let's first start with a mistake:

```
(progv '(a) '(4)
  (funcall (function (third list1))))

Error: (THIRD LIST1) is not a valid argument for FUNCTION.

or similarly:
(progv '(a) '(4)
  (funcall (third list1)))

Error: Argument to apply/funcall is not a function: (LAMBDA NIL (PRINT A)).
```

Then, let's evaluate or compile:

```
(progv '(a) '(4)
  (funcall (eval (third list1))))
4
4
```

or

```
(progv '(a) '(4)
  (funcall (compile nil (third list1))))
Warning in 246: A assumed special
4
4
```

Above is the behaviour I got with LispWorks 7.1. eval didn't give the warning for special assumption, because:

```
(eval (third list1))
#<anonymous interpreted function 40600009EC>
```

eval returned an interpreted function, not compiled. If we further compile, then we'll see the same warning:

```
(eval (third list1))
#<anonymous interpreted function 40600009EC>
(compile nil *)
;;;*** Warning in 248: A assumed special
```

To make things right with progv, since it creates special variables, change the function:

```
(setf list1 '(1 
              1 
              (lambda () 
                (declare (special a))
                (print a))))

(progv '(a) '(4)
  (funcall (compile nil (third list1))))
4
4
```

Note that to make the example politically correct, as CLHS does in progv page, we should better use (progv '(*a*) '(4) ...) and the lambda function should be defined with the *a* variable.